# Multiple Authorizers Support

Tags: security, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I understand that Kafka ships with SimpleACLAuthorizer which support:

1. SSL
2. SASL

Can we implement a custom Authorizer, say - MyCustomAuthorizer (that links to LDAP for user-group assoc.) . And then associate the MyCustomAuthorizer ALONG with the above SimpleACLAuthorizer ?

IN short - Can Kafka support hosting multiple Authorizers at same time ?

One way I can see is that MyCustomAuthorizer can do to implement all 3 ways. But this is not really effective.

```
authorizer.class.name=<Foo.class> <- Supported

authorizer.class.names<Foo.class,Bar.class> <- Is this possible ?
```